# check property value via gdb in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, xcode4

I have set a breakpoint in my code. The code in that line is an if statement

```
if (((RKMappableObjectTableItem *) item).options){
```

now I want to see the value of options when the application breaks at this point, how do I do this in xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a breakpoint and when execution stops open the console (⇧+⌘+Y) and type the following at the gdb prompt:

```
po [((RKMappableObjectTableItem *) item) options]
```

Assuming options is an object, it should work. If it returns a struct try

```
p (Type)[((RKMappableObjectTableItem *) item) options]
```

replacing `Type` with the name of the struct represented by `options`.

Another option is to open the Variables View (use the icons at the top right in the console) in the console and expand the node for the variable item.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is defining a tmp variable and set its value to `options`'s one. Once the application breaks, it should appear in the locals variables list in the bottom of Xcode's window.

Comment: mind showing some code to do that? is this before or after the if statement

Comment: not really, if `options` is, say, a `CGFloat`. just declare a `CGFloat` before the if statement and initialize it with the `options` property value. This var should appear in the list